# Freebase MQL query for non-self of mediator (sibling, spouse, etc.)

Tags: freebase, mql

Is there some way to do an MQL query for the *other* object in a symmetric relationship defined through a mediator type (e.g. `/people/sibling_relationship`)?

For example, suppose I wanted a list of people who have a sister.  The following query returns everyone with a sister, but also includes women who have brothers but no sisters (since they are linked to a sibling relationship containing a female sibling—themselves).

```
[{
  "type": "/people/person",
  "name": null,
  "gender": null,
  "sibling_s": [{
    "sibling": [{
      "name": null,
      "gender": "female"
    }]
  }]
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't a way to deal with the general case.  In your example, you could finesse it by querying women with sisters as sibling relationships where both siblings are female, but generally there's no way to do self-referential stuff in MQL (e.g. an ID not equal to the ID returned in this other part of the query).